# Direct stove/kitchen exhaust into kitchen sink drain

Tags: kitchens, drain, exhaust-vent, exhaust

I live in an apartment that has terrible or zero ventilation for kitchen smells generated while cooking. The exhaust under the Microwave just removes oil from the fumes and circulates the air within the kitchen.

Can I hook a 4inch vent pipe with an inline exhaust fan and direct the exhaust into the kitchen sink drain? That way kitchen smells dont linger for too long, and the hall/dining area, and the rest of the apartment doesn't smell like food I just cooked.

Trying to google it, I don't see anything that addresses my need. But I'm wondering if it'll lead to any issues with the kitchen sink drainage, or the dishwasher that is connected to it. (There's no garbage disposal / insinkerator in this kitchen)

Any advise or suggestion is welcome!

Comment: The problem with this idea is that the smell from the drain will now flow into your kitchen through that vent pipe. That's certainly not the kind of smell I want anywhere in my house, least of all the kitchen.

Comment: I mean, the air will flow from above the gas stove towards the kitchen sink, and into the sink hole. I was thinking of creating a good sealing arrangement for the vent pipe on the sink, so that the vent pipe is fixed only while cooking. And the air will flow down the drain.

Comment: Until you turn the fan off - then the air moves whichever way it wants to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Your traps need to have water in them to prevent sewer gasses from getting into your home. If your vent "seal" was strong enough, you could "clear" the trap allowing gas into the home. Flammable, stinky, potentially deadly gas into the home.

So no. Don't do it.

Comment: Thank you! Thats why I wanted to know if my idea was idiotic or not :)